# In Swift, Array [String] slicing return type doesn't seem to be [String]

Tags: ios, swift, sub-array

I'm slicing an array of strings and setting that to a `[String]` variable, but the type checker is complaining. Is it a possible compiler bug?

```
var tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
tags[1..<3]
var someTags: [String] = tags[1..<3]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Subscripting an array with a range doesn't return an array, but a slice. You can create an array out of that slice though.

```
var tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
tags[1..<3]
var someTags: Slice<String> = tags[1..<3]
var someTagsArray: [String] = Array(someTags)
```

Comment: Where do you find `Slice` documented? Also the error message is incorrect and the `Slice` shows up as [String] in the playground. Thus it seems that there are two compiler errors and missing documentation.

Comment: You can see the definition of the subscipt method here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html

Comment: I agree that the error is incorrect and documentation could use some work. If you try it in two steps: `var someTags = tags[1..<3]
var someTagsArray: [String] = someTags` it gives you the more helpful `error: 'Slice<String>' is not convertible to '[String]'`

Comment: My fault, I looked at the Swift iBooks. I think Apple should remove them of keep them up-to-date.

Comment: But still I do not see documentation about `Slice`, just two lines: `subscript(Range<Int>) -> Slice<T>` and a declaration: `subscript(subRange: Range<Int>) -> Slice<T> { get { } set { } }`.

Comment: @Zaph Look at the `substring` declaration on `Array` here: http://swifter.natecook.com/type/Array/ -- leads to `Slice`: http://swifter.natecook.com/type/Slice/

Comment: Nice, now if only Apple would document Swift. BTW, I have seen your blog, great stuff.

Comment: So, this being the case, if I want a function that'll take an array, or a slice, or anything else of that ilk, what signature should it have?

Comment: With Swift 3 I'm getting an error on the third line, "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'indexable'".

Comment: Just wondering. Why are there distinctions between a slice of an array and an array? It seems very conterintuitive.

Answer (score 14):

```
var tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
var someTags: [String] = Array(tags[1..<3])
println("someTags: \(someTags)") // "someTags: [is, cool]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that in one place is combine variable declaration `let someTags: [String]` and [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map), that will transform `ArraySlice<String>` to `[String]`:

```
let tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
let someTags: [String] = tags[1..<3].map { $0 } // ["is", "cool"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this to get a new array of the slice:

```
var tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
var someTags = [String]()
someTags += tags[1..<3]
println(someTags[0])  //prints ["is", "cool"]
```

Comment: It's OK, but it's confusing.

Comment: I expected it'll print "is"

Answer (score 0):

Another convenient way to convert an `ArraySlice` to `Array` is this:

`var tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
var someTags: [String] = tags[1..<3] + []`

It's not perfect because another developer (or yourself) who looks at it later may not understand its purpose. The good news is that if that developer (maybe you) removes the `+ []` they will immediately be met with a compiler error, which will hopefully clarify its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the slice as an Array when it's created. Keeping your Array as an array without having to use an intermediate variable. This works great when using Codable types.

```
var tags = ["this", "is", "cool"]
tags = Array(tags[1..<3])
```