# Cannot assign value of type 'ArraySlice<User>' to type '[User]'

Tags: ios, swift

I want to divide Model array into two different arrays  by using prefix , postfix

```
let data = serverResponse.data as! [User]
collectionData = data.prefix(upTo: 10)
tableData =  data.suffix(from: 11)
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33830047/1187415,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/25714673/1187415

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to convert the array slices returned by `prefix` and `suffix` to arrays by calling the initializer of `Array` accepting an `ArraySlice`.

```
let data = serverResponse.data as! [User]
collectionData = Array(data.prefix(upTo: 10))
tableData =  Array(data.suffix(from: 11))
```